# Declaring multiple variables using the same function in Python

Tags: python

Long-hand this is how it would look like:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def f(num):
        """In general, a complicated function."""
        return num

    self.a = f(1)
    self.b = f(2)
    self.c = f(3)
    self.d = f(4)
    self.e = f(5)
```

I'm thinking dictionary methods could help, but how?

Comment: how about this `a, b, c, d, e = [f(i) for i in range(1,6)]`

Comment: I find that if I copy-paste and then manually change the arguments, it's more prone to errors. For example, I can end up writing `self.b = f(1)` if I'm not careful. I'd like to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: then I recommend lists `array = [f(i) for i in range(1,6)]` but if you like dict look at the Kasramvd answer

Comment: Thanks @Azad! I think the list is better for few variable names so they'd fit in the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you better to use a dictionary.And as a more pythonic way you can use a dictionary comprehension.You can use `enumerate` to create a sequence of keys for your dictionary based on your items index. :

```
>>> my_dict = {'a{}'.format(i):f(j) for i,j in enumerate([3,4,5,1,2])}
{'a1': 4, 'a0': 3, 'a3': 1, 'a2': 5, 'a4': 2}
```

And for accessing to each value you can use a simple indexing :

```
>>> my_dict['a3']
1
```

Also if you want to use custom names for your keys you can use `zip` function to zip the variable names with values the use if within a dict comprehension:

```
>>> var_names=['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> values=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> 
>>> my_dict = {i:f(j) for i,j in zip(var_names,values)}
>>> my_dict
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd rather keep them as separate variable names, but I think this is neater when I use more than 5 variables.

Comment: @irene Indeed, the first approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

You're going in the wrong direction - if you want to assign several references based on the same function, you should be storing them in a data structure like a `list` instead of in discrete, manually-entered variables. You can unpack them like that later if you want, but you should start with a data structure. It then becomes easier to `map()` each value in an iterable to this function, and then turn it into a `list`.

```
def f(num):
    """In general, a complicated function."""
    return num

my_numbers = list(map(f, range(1, 6)))
```

Your numbers were a tidy range this time so I just used a `range()` object, but you can use any iterable you like, such as `[1, 2, 3]` or `(4, 2, 3)`.

Comment: The map() function is new to me. I may have difficulty in bookkeeping (which index corresponds to which variable), but it's an interesting method nonetheless. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Basically, any time you find yourself manually creating variable names that follow a sequence, like `label1`, `label2`, `label3`, etc., you've got a problem, because adding elements means your script gets bigger and more difficult to work with. Note how the method above would take no more code for `range(1, 1000)` than it does for `range(1, 6)`.